# AT+CIPSEND command closed the connection automatically

Tags: esp8266

[image]

I don't know why `CIPSEND` command closed the connection after sending done without `CIPCLOSE` command. Is it normal?

If I want to keep the connection, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Perhaps it is an appropriate result of the "Connection: close" header?

Comment: I has changed to "keep-alive". It's still the same result. :(
I'm using Ajax jquery to take the data from Adruino. May Ajax has closed the connection automatically after receiving done? Im newbie in ajax.

Comment: I don't think anyone is required to honor a keep alive header sent by the other party, it is more of a suggestion.  But it may not be your issue either.  Maybe you should try something else against the server, or the ESP8266 against something else.